# python how to get all kind names in google cloud datastore

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am wondering how to retrieve all kind names that are stored in the `google cloud datastore` in `Python`. I am thinking of using a `query`,

```
client = datastore.Client()
query = client.query()
results = query.fetch()
```

but it only gets all the entities stored by the default `client`. So how to get all the kinds' names in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a [kind metadata query](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/metadataqueries#kind_queries) to fetch the kind names.

If you're using the Google Cloud Python library, it would look like:

```
query = client.query(kind='__kind__')
query.keys_only()

kinds = [entity.key.id_or_name for entity in query.fetch()]
```

Comment: I tried the code, but `kinds` also contains some build-in kinds, e.g. `<class 'list'>: ['_AE_DatastoreAdmin_Operation', '_GAE_MR_TaskPayload', '__Stat_Kind_IsRootEntity__', '__Stat_Kind_NotRootEntity__', '__Stat_Kind__', '__Stat_PropertyName_Kind__', '__Stat_PropertyType_Kind__', '__Stat_PropertyType_PropertyName_Kind__', '__Stat_PropertyType__', '__Stat_Total__']`, I'm wondering how to retain only the kinds' name that created by the user.

Answer (score 0):

```py
In [15]: set([entity.kind for entity in client.query().fetch()])
Out[15]: {'SomeKind', 'AnotherKind'}
```